# VS cannot show information on variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some arbitrary code. e.g. the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    private MyClass() { }
    public static readonly MyClass Instance = new MyClass();
    public Hashtable DoSomething() {return new Hashtable {{"key", "value"}};}
}

var test = MyClass.Instance.DoSomething();
```

Now when debugging and hovering `test` intellisense doesn´t show anything at all. Also adding a watch to the variable does not work. Instead the message

> The name 'test' does not exist in the current context

appears. I already rebuilt the solution, closed VS and re-opened it. However when NOT debugging I get type-information on that variable within intellisense.

NB: Unfortunetaly the code above works within my test-solution, however the actual code which is far more complex does not. I already tried to simplify this as much as I can, supposing some downvotes as the error is hardly to reproduce. However maybe anyone has had a similar problem on VS.

EDIT: Optimization of code is disabled within projects settings (Properties-->Build-->optimize code)

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is: are you sure you built for 'Debug', not 'Release' ?

Comment: If you mean Project-Properties-->Build-->Configuration to be set `Active (Debug)` or something similar then it actually IS built dor `Debug`.

Comment: @TTT What's the problem if it's release ?

Comment: @aguetat - In release build, unused variables may be optimized away

Comment: @HansKesting Even on `Release` the test-solution showed all the variables content accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler most likely optimizes the variable away because it is never used locally.

Use the variable in any way to circumvent this:

```
     var test = MyClass.Instance.DoSomething();
     Debug.WriteLine(test); // <=== Set breakpoint here
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think optimizations also affect this. So to be sure, turn them off if you have these problems.

Comment: Is it because `test` is never used locally?

Comment: yes, exactly. If you use the variable in any way, then you can debug it. Also turn off optimizations to prevent these things

Comment: However I do not see why the same works within the small test-solution.

Comment: @HimBromBeere done, it's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code.